# How to trigger notifications when item added to or removed from Core Data NSManagedObject relationship's NSSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsset

What is the correct way to trigger an `NSNotification` whenever an item is added to or removed from a to-many relationship / `NSSet` within a custom `NSManagedObject` subclass?

I have a custom `NSManagedObject` subclass that has a one-to-many unordered relationship to another `NSManagedObject` subclass. For clarity, let's say these two subclasses are `Teacher` and `Student`, where one `Teacher` can have multiple `Student` objects but where each `Student` is only assigned to one `Teacher`.

I'd like to be able to trigger a notification whenever a `Student` is added to or removed from a `Teacher`, whether because `Student` was simply assigned to or from a `Teacher` or whether because `Student` was deleted entirely from Core Data.

I tried using KVO but it doesn't seem like you can <del>add an observer to an `NSSet`'s `count` property</del> add an observer to a `@dynamic` property. Additionally, I tried implementing my own custom to-many accessor method as outlined in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html), but in testing it seems like my custom accessor methods are never called. In case there is something wrong with my implementation, here is how I implemented it within `Teacher`:

```
@implementation Teacher

@dynamic students;

- (void)addStudentsObject:(Student *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                   usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveStudents] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                  usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_TEACHER_STUDENT_WAS_ADDED object:self];
}

- (void)removeStudentsObject:(Student *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
                   usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveStudents] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
                  usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_TEACHER_STUDENT_WAS_REMOVED object:self];
}

- (void)addStudents:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                   usingObjects:values];
    [[self primitiveStudents] unionSet:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
                  usingObjects:values];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_TEACHER_STUDENTS_WERE_ADDED object:self];
}

- (void)removeStudents:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
                withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
                   usingObjects:values];
    [[self primitiveStudents] minusSet:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(students))
               withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
                  usingObjects:values];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_TEACHER_STUDENTS_WERE_REMOVED object:self];
}

...

@end
```

Comment: I believe you simply need to override the `setStudents` and accessor, calling `setPrimitiveStudents` after using `primitiveStudents` to delta the two sets. 
What the docs have you re-implementing are not the standard accessors for the `students` property.  Think of them as convenience accessors in the way that there are designated and convenience initializers.  You have ensured that they're KVO-compliant, but you haven't ensured that other code uses them.  Also, if you want to use KVO, you have to KVO observe the `students` keypath, and you could  get both the old and new sets in that code.

Comment: How do I override `setStudents` and its accessor? I saw the section "Custom Primitive Accessor Methods" in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html but could not figure out how to implement it as I didn't know where you defined `nonCompliantKVCivar`.

Comment: Typo. "and" should be omitted from that comment.  `setStudents` is the setter accessor for the students property.  `-(void) setStudents:(NSSet*)students{    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"students"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:students forKey:@"students"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"students"]; }`  Try inserting your notification in there.  Or, like I said, use KVO on the `students` keypath.  In any event, the accessors you implemented just aren't used by any standard controllers.  A 3rd option is a change notification for the MOC.

Comment: Thank you! Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue turns out to be that the fancy accessor examples in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html) that you were using as a reference are actually not *all* the accessors for the relationship.  They are extra convenience accessors that you can implement if you want.  But because you are trying to insert your code by overriding all the setters (or whatever you want to call mutating accessors), you need to also override the most basic setter.

The most basic accessors for a to-many relationship are setters and getters for the `NSSet` object for the entire relationship.  In your case, `- (NSSet*) students` and `- (void) setStudents:(NSSet*)students`.

So, at a minimum, your notification needs to be posted in `setStudents`:

```
-(void) setStudents:(NSSet*)students{ 
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"students"]; 
    [self setPrimitiveValue:students forKey:@"students"]; 
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"students"]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_TEACHER_STUDENTS_WERE_ADDED object:self];

}
```

*That* is the setter being used by default.